# ImageView selectableItemBackgroundBorderless does not render outside of view bounds

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, android-button, rippledrawable

I am using `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to add a ripple to an `ImageView`.
My expected behaviour would be to have a circular ripple, extending the views size. Unfortunately the ripple gets cropped by the view bounds.
How can this issue be solved?

**Default state:**

[image: default state]

**Pressed state:**

[image: cropped ripple]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_instruction_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_gradient_bg"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_sign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_sign"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="2"
        tools:text="A644 Shudehill asdfkjasdf asdfasdf asdfsss"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_sign"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:text="via Church St"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nav_queue_sheet_icon_light"
        android:id="@+id/nav_queue"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you getting that "pressed state" without having the `clickable` attribute set to the ImageView in the xml?

Comment: AFAIK you don't need the clickable attribute if you attach a click listener

Comment: can you solve this

Answer (score 15):

If you have a clickable `ImageView`, then most possibly it should be an `ImageButton` instead.

Having defined following `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigation_black_24dp" />
```

Then you'll get following output:

[image]

If you want bigger ripple effect, you have to change view's size: instead of `wrap_content` make it, let's say, 100dp:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a background color to your view (so I can see it's boundaries) and use the ripple as foreground?

Comment: For that purpose I have turned on "show layout bounds" developer option. The square you see in gifs is the boundary of the view.

Answer (score 3):

Define `ripple_effect_circle.xml` in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#BDBDBD"
    >

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="60dp"
                android:height="60dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#BDBDBD" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Define `ImageView` in layout

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ripple_effect_circle"
            android:background="@drawable/your_round_image"
            />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change from using `ImageView`'s foreground to **background**: `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`. Then you should see the ripple render outside of the view bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView for this issue.

Create the circular Imageview with the above library and it will be having the ripple effect as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is your limiting the height of the `ImageView` by `46dp` add  `padding` to `ImageView` instead of Parent layout

Answer (score 0):

do  layerlist drawable xml
make the first item shape circle
then add item selectableItemBackgroundBorderless 
and it will work fine