# Unbound Ripple/Indication in Jetpack Compose (equivalent to selectableBackgroundBorderless)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose the `clickable` Modifier will by default use `LocalIndication.current` and show a ripple that is bound to the border. That looks great almost always, but there are some circumstances where a rounded, unbound ripple looks better. Back in View Android we would've used `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to achieve this behaviour. How can we do it in compose?

Example [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511587/imageview-selectableitembackgroundborderless-does-not-render-outside-of-view-bou):

[image: 2]

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can customise the ripple effect as follow:

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false), // You can also change the color and radius of the ripple
    onClick = {}
)
```

Comment: Any idea how to change the alpha of the colour of the indication??

Comment: @Nik a bit late answer but, here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68610270/4376058 you can find how to define and set RippleTheme. Instead of using defaultRippleAlpha just create yours like this ` = RippleAlpha(
        draggedAlpha = 0f,
        focusedAlpha = 0f,
        hoveredAlpha = 0f,
        pressedAlpha = 1f
    )
`