# Ripple with rounded corners Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ripple-effect, android-compose-card

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387035/unbound-ripple-indication-in-jetpack-compose-equivalent-to-selectablebackground/66388565#66388565) answer I got wrong ripple animation. Do you know how to create ripple with rounded corners using Jetpack Compose?

With default ripple I have this:
[image: Ripple]

Code:

```kotlin
Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = buttonColor(LocalContext.current)),
        backgroundColor = backColor(LocalContext.current),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = rememberRipple(radius = 30.dp)
            ) { show = !show }
    ) { ... } //Show is animation of other element.
```

//If I put radius of ripple 200 dp(it's a height of card) ripple works not normal.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Starting with M2 [**`1.0.0-beta08`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.0.0-beta08) you can solve this issue using the **`onClick`** lambda parameter in the `Card` instead of the `clickable` modifier:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(10.dp),
    onClick = { show = !show }
){
  //card content
}
```

If you need the **`clickable`** or the **`combinedClickable`** modifier you have to use the variant **without** the `onClick` parameter and to apply also the `clip` modifier to the `Card` using the same `Card` shape:

```
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)

Card(
    shape = shape,
    modifier = Modifier
        //...height, width, padding
        .clip(shape)
        .combinedClickable(
            onLongClick =  { /** do something */ },
            onClick = { /** do something */ }
        )
){
   //card content
}
```

With M3 `Card` you can do the same.

---

Until `1.0.0-beta07` applying a `.clickable` modifier to the `Card` the ripples aren't clipped by the bounds of the layout.

As workaround you can apply the `.clickable` modifier to the content of the Card (for example a `Box`):

```
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = Color.Blue),
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)

    ) {
        Box(Modifier
              .clickable(
                  onClick = { /* ...*/ }
              )
        ){
            Text("Text")
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I click on the 1st side of element it works normal but if I click on the 2nd side ripple effect goes over corner.

Comment: @RenatteleRenattele what is 1st side and 2nd side?

Comment: Random dots on element.

Comment: @RenatteleRenattele It seems a bug of the Card. The ripples aren't clipped by the bounds of the layout. Posted a workaround.

Comment: edit: For anyone reading this in late 2022, the material3 library has the same issue, but has no onClick argument that can be used. The workaround provided with using an interior box seems to work though!

Comment: @Nathan It is not correct. M3 Card API has the onClick [variant](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Card(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.CardColors,androidx.compose.material3.CardElevation,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1))

Comment: I apologize, it looks like it's indeed behind the experimental api, and you can opt in with `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)`. I need long press, and it seems like that requires a `combinedClickable` Modifier, however the modifier isn't accepting `onLongClick` without `onClick` as well. I tried it with `onClick` (when the onClick argument is also passed directly to the Card), and it seems like the `combinedClickable -> onClick` argument is just getting discarded. Do you happen to know what the correct approach is here? (edit: if this is out of scope I can make a separate question)

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Just fyi it looks like in my case the shape that matches the M3 card default shape has rounded corners of ~`11.dp`, not sure if that's universal or just because of the way I'm using it.

Comment: Order is important: set shape, clip to shape, set clickable

Answer (score 33):

I've so far identified 2 options:

1. In addition to setting the shape, use `.clip` modifier to clip the Card using the same shape:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
        .clickable {
                //do something
        }
) {
    Box {
        Text("Text")
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that the elevation shadow gets clips as well, so your Card loses it's shadow.

2. Set the `.clickable` on the Card content composable:

```
 Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                //do something
        }
    ) {
        Text("Text")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `clip` option works perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

I checked the sources of Card/Surface composables and found out that you need to have background and clip modifiers with the same shape. So for example the following Box has rounded corner shape and click ripple is cut with the same bounds:

```
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(
            color = Color.Yellow,
            shape = shape
        )
        .clip(shape)
        .clickable { onClick() },
) {
 // your content here
}
```

Comment: This works with the `M3` and `1.1.0-alpha08` version.

Answer (score 13):

**Hope this will grant you the easiest solution**

> *Just add* **.clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))** *in the ***modifier*** parameter*

**Here is the full code :**

```
Card(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(30.dp)
    .size(100.dp)
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp))
    .clickable {
        // After clip //
    }) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

using `rememberRipple(bounded = false)` will give a circular ripple effect around the clicked component. It can be used as ->

```
Modifier.clickable(
             indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false),
             interactionSource = remember {
                        MutableInteractionSource()
                    }
            ) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Material 3 1.5.0 or above You can do something like this.

```
modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer, 
             MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
            .clickable { onClickOfNewsITem(article.url ?: "") }
```

Just make sure you apply `clip` property before `onClick`. In Compose the order of property matters. because compose draw Ui in a top-to-bottom approach.

Read details - [The three phases of a frame](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/phases)

Answer (score 0):

When you use long press or other gesture,you can use modifier.indication

```kotlin
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Card(
    modifier = Modifier
      .padding(12.dp, 6.dp)
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
      .indication(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current)
      .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures(
          onPress = { offset ->
            val press = PressInteraction.Press(offset)
            interactionSource.emit(press)
            tryAwaitRelease()
            interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
          },
          onLongPress = {},
          onTap = {}
        )
      }
  )
```