# Change color of Ripple for IconButton in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ripple, iconbutton

This is not a duplicate of [Modify ripple color of IconButton in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265345/modify-ripple-color-of-iconbutton-in-jetpack-compose) This question was diverted in a different way...

I am trying to change the IconButton ripple colour as follows

```
IconButton(

        modifier = modifier
            .indication(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = rememberRipple(
                    bounded = false,
                    radius = 30.dp,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.error_red)
                )
            )
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white), shape = CircleShape),
        onClick = { onButtonPressed() }
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_busy_small_busy),
            contentDescription = buttonContentDesc,
        )
    }
```

The ripple colour does not change. It stays dark Grey.
Also, Is there a way to change the alpha of the ripple??

Comment: The question is the same and also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266346/2016562): your code doesn't work since the Ripple is implemented in a `.clickable` modifier defined inside the `IconButton`.

Comment: Thank you @GabrieleMariotti The answer helped me in some way. Now that the colour is changing and I can control the Alpha, the radius cannot be changed as I am no more using ```indication = rememberRipple(
                    bounded = false,
                    radius = 30.dp,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.error_red)
                )```

Any idea how to that when using the ripple theme

Answer (score 0):

Now you have a colors variable for IconButton:

```
IconButton(
                    colors = IconButtonDefaults.iconButtonColors(
                        containerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.primary),
                        contentColor = Color.White
                    ),
                    onClick = {
                    // Action
                }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit, contentDescription = null)
                }
```